# Can't pause webBrowser1_Navigating event in winform. c#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I try to record some internet activity through mouse hook in webbrowser control in winform application. Vary rare happens to click to a link and to not record that click just because everything happens too quickly and my code in

```
public void WebBrowser1Document_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {    
            tempHtmlElement = webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement;
            ...
```

method couldn't reach to the end. In 90% record happens but some time it passes `webBrowser1_Navigating` event after that as I said passes `WebBrowser1Document_Click` just the beginning and `webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement` breaks. It doesn't matter I have variable for the ActiveElement this variable looses access to some properties as Name for example. So my question is how to pause webbrowser1 activity until record is made. It's a STA application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Navigation occurs before Click method completes, You can pause by a tricky method. Use a global variable CanNavigate.

```
bool canNavigate;
public void WebBrowser1Document_Click(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
        {    
            canNavigate=false;
            tempHtmlElement = webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement;
            ...
            ...
            //At the End 
            canNavigate=true;
         }




    void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            do
            {
Application.DoEvents(); Thread.Sleep(100);

            } while (!canNavigate);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The idea is great. I would upvote but it's not allowed.

Comment: You are welcome. If your browser moves faster than the first line of ducument_clik then you can set canNavigate=false somewhere before clicking :)